# In how many ways can we choose $n$ items from $k$ distinct types of items put in a circle?

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can we choose $n$ items from $k$ distinct types of items put in a circle, where every type has infinity items.

This is my thought:

Suppose $f(n,k)$ is the result of problem.

I'll build recursive form, and I think:
$$f(n,k)=f(n-1,k)+f(n,k-1)$$
But it may be the wrong answer.

An example: With $n=3$,$k=2$, we have: $f(3,2)=4$.

Explanation : $k=2$ types of items is {$0,1$} we have: $(0,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$, $(1,1,0)$, $(1,1,1)$.

So $f(3,2)=4$.

Another example: With $n=4$,$k=2$, we have $f(4,2)=6$.

Explanation: $k=2$ types of items is {$0,1$} we have: $(0,0,0,0)$, $(0,0,0,1)$, $(0,0,1,1)$, $(0,1,0,1)$, $(0,1,1,1)$, $(1,1,1,1)$

So $f(4,2)=6$.

Comment: thanks for your useful !!!1 I'll try edit it!!!

Comment: It would seem that you are trying to count [combinatorial necklaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics)).  The usual approach in counting these is to use [Polya's enumeration theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_enumeration_theorem) and [the lemma that is not Burnside's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma).

Comment: I'm thanks so much !!!